# Simplify sql query(date to period)

Tags: sql, date, simplify, period

got this table:
[initial table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YmlB.png)

Need to get table like this:
[Target table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ6VA.png)

what I used:

```
Select ID_CLIENT, BALANCE, HIST_DT as Start_dt, isnull(lead(hist_dt) over (partition by id_client order by hist_dt asc), '2999.12.31') as End_dt
from (
select ID_CLIENT, ID_STATUS, balance, hist_dt, lag(id_status) over (partition by id_client order by id_status) as Prev_ID_status
from Client_History) a
where a.ID_STATUS = a.Prev_ID_status or a.ID_STATUS = 1
order by ID_CLIENT, HIST_DT
```

I think its very complicated. Will be glad to hear any suggestions of simplyfing this query.

Comment: I think you can make a query on whenever your `Balance` changes for `id_client`

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, most easily solved with the difference of row numbers and aggregation:

```
select id_client, balance, min(hist_dt), max(hist_dt)
from (select ch.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_client order by balance_hist_dt) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id_client, balance order by balance_hist_dt) as seqnum_2
      from client_history ch
     ) ch
group by id_client, balance, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by id_client, min(hist_dt);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to describe.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference captures adjacent rows with the same balance.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Read some information about this problem. But dont quite get the first underscore in balance_hist_dt in your query

Comment: @Stepnosound . . . I don't know what you mean by "get the first underscore".

Comment: There are two column: balance, and hist_dt. And in your query they stick together with "_"

Comment: @Stepnosound . . . I revised the answer.